# Heroku - GIT Deployment Task :npmInstall FAILED

Tags: heroku, npm, jhipster

I initialized a JHipster project and tried to deploy it to heroku. I did nothing more than that and get the error below. Im not sure where the problem is, either the Jhipster release im using or Heroku i think. Should i try switching to another version of JHipster, or could this possibly be an issue of my local setup (npm-, node-, java-, gralde-version)?

**JHipster Version(s)**

```
    generator-jhipster@6.10.1
```

**JHipster configuration**

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "io.profit.testify",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.10.1",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "priv",
    "packageName": "io.profit.testify",
    "packageFolder": "io/profit/testify",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "YourJWTSecretKeyWasReplacedByThisMeaninglessTextByTheJHipsterInfoCommandForObviousSecurityReasons",
    "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "creationTimestamp": 1595760910320,
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": ["en", "de"],
    "blueprints": [],
    "herokuAppName": "afternoon-falls-71420",
    "herokuDeployType": "git",
    "herokuJavaVersion": "11"
  }
}
```

**Environment and Tools**

java version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)

git version 2.20.1.windows.1

node: v12.2.0

npm: 6.9.0

yeoman: 3.1.1

**Error From Heroku Console:**

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
remote:        .................................................................................................
remote:        To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
remote:        Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
remote:        > Task :bootBuildInfo
remote:        > Task :nodeSetup SKIPPED
remote:        > Task :npmSetup SKIPPED
remote:        > Task :npmInstall FAILED
remote:
remote:        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
remote:
remote:        * What went wrong:
remote:        Execution failed for task ':npmInstall'.
remote:        > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''
```

Comment: If you use git deployment it's not a problem with your local environment. Let me check it seems like a bug or an npm issue.

Comment: Can you check the output before "Downloading ...". It should show the executed command. It must be "executing ./gradlew stage -Pprod -PnodeInstall". As nodeSetup is skipped it looks like the app cconfiguration on heroku is incorrect, but I can't reproduce it with jhipster 6.10.1. I see your appname is different from the heroku app name. Was it randomly generated? Maybe in that case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the correct gradle task you can set it manually via heroku cli:

```
heroku config:set GRADLE_TASK="stage -Pprod -PnodeInstall"
```

In case the buildpack is not correctly set configure it via

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/gradle
```

After that try pushing again via

```
git push heroku master
```

And the build should work again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first command did the trick.